# Scala Singleton object for an extended class and pass parameters

Tags: scala

I have a problem in creating a singleton in Scala for a class with parameters and which is extending an abstract class. I need to write all the logic in the class because I shouldn't miss any features of abstract class and have to limit it to accessing only one way by using a Scala `object`.

Below `GenerateCountryAnimal` needs to be created as a singleton.

```
abstract class Animal {            
  def giveAnimalData(): DataFrame            
}

// The following must be a singleton.
// I have to implement all my logic in this class and acquire all the features of Animal
class GenerateCountryAnimal(tableA: Table, tableB: Table) extends Animal {
  // implement giveAnimalData method
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. Your "question" is literally just a piece of code. You didnt even ask any question.

Comment: @FabianSchöner , I have added required comments . Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: try `object` keyword instead of `class`

Comment: object will give me wrong top declaration error. Scala object can't take parameters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, singletons are normally represented by an `object`. In your case, you can still use it by extending your original `abstract class` with another one that implements your logic, and then have different `object`s depending on your needs:

```
abstract class Animal {            
  def giveAnimalData(): DataFrame            
}

abstract class GenerateCountryAnimal(tableA: Table, tableB: Table) extends Animal {
  // implement giveAnimalData method
}

object YourSingleton extends GenerateCountryAnimal(??? : Table, ??? : Table)
```

If you need to get those parameters at runtime you may want take advantage of the fact that `object`s are created lazily:

```
// The object will be created only when first referred to and you can use
// this characteristic to set the value of tableA and tableB to those that
// are relevant for you
object GenerateCountryAnimal extends Animal {
  val tableA: Table = ???
  val tableB: Table = ???
  def giveAnimalData(): DataFrame = ???
}
```

Otherwise, you may want to simply port the singleton pattern to Scala, which is thoroughly described in [this post](http://blogs.tedneward.com/patterns/Singleton-Scala/).

Comment: Thanks for explanation . I can use first example because I can know dependencies of that object by looking itself

Answer (score 1):

A "singleton with parameters" doesn't make very much sense. Singleton means there is a single instance of the class in the entire system. If that's the case, it does not need any parameters.

I am assuming you don't really need a single instance, but rather one instance per parameter combination. This is called "canonicalization". The idea is that you make a map where you keep your canonical instances, and a factory method, that manages it:

```
   object Animal {

        import java.util.function.Function
        import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

        private class GenerateCountryAnimal(tableA: Table, tableB: Table) extends Animal {
           // your implementation here
        }
        object Factory extends Function[(Table, Table), Animal] {
          def apply(key: (Table, Table)) = new GenerateCountryAnimal(key._1, key._2) 
        }
        val canon = new ConcurrentHashMap[(Table,Table), Animal]()
        def apply(a: Table, b: Table) = canon
           .computeIfAbsent((a,b), Factory)
   }
```

This way, you can do `val animal = Animal(foo, bar)` and that will always return the same instance for the same pair of arguments. 
(I am assuming your `Table` thingy has `hasCode` and `equals` working properly, so that it can be used as a key in hash map).

To be clear, *I highly doubt what you are doing is actually a good idea*. 
While exceptions are possible, there is usually no need to canonicalize your instances like this in scala. Unless you have some specific obscure reason not to, you should just make your `GenerateCountryAnimal` a case class, and instantiate it as needed with `GenerateCountryAnimal(a,b)`.

If there is any specific resource inside of it, that you want to be a singleton, then make *that* a singleton (the way the other answer describes).